# Raycaster.intersectObjects always returns me the exactly same array when I change the mouse position

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to use this sample code - https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_postprocessing_outline.html to outline models with some changes.

Changes are:

1. When the scene loads for the first time, I render only a grid helper and a plane-buffer on top of it
2. On every mousedown event, I add an OBJ to the scene.

The issue is:

Whenever I move the mouse in the scene, I am getting the same intersect objects. As in, suppose I have only plane-buffer geometry in the scene and I move the mouse, the intersect distances never change for me. Now, if I add multiple models in the scene and move the mouse, the intersect object's size changes but the distances remain the same independent of the mouse move event.

I am sorry for the commented codes here: trying a lot of things to make it work. Please have patience.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - loaders - OBJ loader</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #000;
                color: #fff;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #info {
                color: #fff;
                position: absolute;
                top: 10px;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                z-index: 100;
                display:block;
            }
            #info a, .button { color: #f00; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="info">
        <a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener">three.js</a> - OBJLoader test
        </div>

        <script src="../build/three.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
        <script src="js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>

        <script src="js/WebGL.js"></script>

        <script src="js/shaders/CopyShader.js"></script>
        <script src="js/shaders/FXAAShader.js"></script>
        <script src="js/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js"></script>
        <script src="js/postprocessing/RenderPass.js"></script>
        <script src="js/postprocessing/ShaderPass.js"></script>
        <script src="js/postprocessing/OutlinePass.js"></script>

        <script>

            var container;

            var camera, scene, renderer;

            var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

            var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            var object;
            var controls;
            var mouse;
            var objects = [];
            var loader;
            var manager;
            var pickedObject, pickedObjectSavedColor;
            const pickPosition = {x: 0, y: 0};
            var outlinePass, composer, renderPass, effectFXAA;
            var selectedObjects = [];
            var textureLoader;
            var texture;
            var INTERSECTED;
            var obj3d = new THREE.Object3D();
            var group = new THREE.Group();

            init();
            animate();


            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 20000 );
                // camera.position.z = 250;
                camera.position.set( 300, 300, 300 );
                camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );


                // scene

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x000000 );

                var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xcccccc, 0.4 );
                scene.add( ambientLight );

                var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
                camera.add( pointLight );
                scene.add( camera );

                var gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper( 4000, 20 );
                scene.add( gridHelper );


                raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
                mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

                // sets the boundary
                var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 2000, 2000 );
                geometry.rotateX( - Math.PI / 2 );

                plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { visible: true } ) );
                scene.add( group )
                group.add( obj3d )
                group.add( plane )
                // scene.add( plane );


                // objects.push( plane );

                // manager

                function loadModel() {

                    if ( object ) {
                        object.traverse( function ( child ) {

                        if ( child.isMesh ) child.material.map = texture;

                        } );

                        // object.position.y = 20;
                        object.scale.set(2.54, 2.54, 2.54);
                        scene.add( object );
                    }

                }

                manager = new THREE.LoadingManager( loadModel );

                manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {

                    console.log( item, loaded, total );

                };

                // texture

                textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader( manager );

                // var texture = textureLoader.load( 'models/obj/52329571/mid/diffuse_2048.png' );

                // model

                function onProgress( xhr ) {

                    if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {

                        var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                        console.log( 'model ' + Math.round( percentComplete, 2 ) + '% downloaded' );

                    }

                }

                function onError() {}

                loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );

                // loader.load( 'models/obj/52329571/mid/52329571_mid.obj', function ( obj ) {

                //  object = obj;

                // }, onProgress, onError );



                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
                controls.addEventListener( 'change', animate ); // call this only in static scenes (i.e., if there is no animation loop)
                // controls.enableDamping = true; // an animation loop is required when either damping or auto-rotation are enabled
                // controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
                controls.screenSpacePanning = false;
                // controls.minDistance = 100;
                // controls.maxDistance = 500;
                // controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;
                controls.update();

                composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer );

                renderPass = new THREE.RenderPass( scene, camera );
                composer.addPass( renderPass );

                outlinePass = new THREE.OutlinePass(new THREE.Vector2(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight), scene, camera);
                composer.addPass( outlinePass );

                effectFXAA = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.FXAAShader);
                effectFXAA.uniforms['resolution'].value.set(1 / window.innerWidth, 1 / window.innerHeight);
                effectFXAA.renderToScreen = true;
                composer.addPass(effectFXAA);

                document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

                //

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
                window.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
                windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

                var x, y;

                if ( event.changedTouches ) {

                    x = event.changedTouches[ 0 ].pageX;
                    y = event.changedTouches[ 0 ].pageY;

                } else {

                    x = event.clientX;
                    y = event.clientY;

                }

                pickPosition.x = ( x / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
                pickPosition.y = - ( y / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
                checkIntersection();
                animate();
            }

            function checkIntersection() {
                // // console.log("Checking intersection");

                // var vector = new THREE.Vector3(pickPosition.x, pickPosition.y, 1);
                // vector.unproject(camera);

                // var ray = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());
                // console.log(objects)
                // var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( objects, true );

                // if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
                //  // console.log("intersects: ", intersects);

                //  if (intersects[0].object != INTERSECTED) {
                //      // console.log(" NEW intersect: ", intersects);

                //       // restore previous intersection object (if it exists) to its original color
                //      if (INTERSECTED)
                //          // INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex(INTERSECTED.currentHex);
                //        // store reference to closest object as current intersection object
                //        // console.log("previous object: ", INTERSECTED)
                //        INTERSECTED = intersects[0].object;
                //        // console.log("new object: ", INTERSECTED)
                //        // store color of closest object (for later restoration)
                //        // INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.material.color.getHex();
                //        // set a new color for closest object
                //        // INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex(0xffff00);
                //      }
                // } else // there are no intersections
                // {
                //  console.log("No intersection")
                //     // restore previous intersection object (if it exists) to its original color
                //     if (INTERSECTED)
                //       // INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex(INTERSECTED.currentHex);
                //     // remove previous intersection object reference
                //     //     by setting current intersection object to "nothing"
                //     INTERSECTED = null;
                // }

                  // controls.update();
                raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
                var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( [ scene ], true );
                console.log(intersects)
                if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
                    var selectedObject = intersects[ 0 ].object;
                    addSelectedObject( selectedObject );
                    outlinePass.selectedObjects = selectedObjects;
                } else {
                    // outlinePass.selectedObjects = [];
                }
            }

            function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
                // console.log("mouse down event received")
                // the following line would stop any other event handler from firing
                // (such as the mouse's TrackballControls)
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log("mouse down received")

                mouse.set( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1 );

                raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

                var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children, true );

                if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

                    var intersect = intersects[ 0 ];

                    // delete cube
                    // delete object feature call
                    if ( false ) {

                        if ( intersect.object !== plane ) {

                            scene.remove( intersect.object );

                            objects.splice( objects.indexOf( intersect.object ), 1 );

                        }

                        // create cube

                    } else {
                        console.log("onDocumentMouseDown call to obj loader first object")

                        // objLoaderFunction(loader, textureMap, intersect)
                        // var voxel = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeo, cubeMaterial );
                        // console.log("objLoaderFunction call complete")
                        // objMesh.position.copy( intersect.point ).add( intersect.face.normal );
                        // // voxel.position.divideScalar( 50 ).floor().multiplyScalar( 50 ).addScalar( 25 );
                        // scene.add( objMesh );

                        // objects.push( objMesh );

                        // call for another image here
                        //textures/50219063/low
                        // console.log("onDocumentMouseDown call to obj loader second object")
                        // objLoaderFunction(loader, textureMap1)

                        texture = textureLoader.load( 'models/obj/52329571/mid/diffuse_2048.png' );

                        loader.load( 'models/obj/52329571/mid/52329571_mid.obj', function ( obj ) {

                            object = obj;
                            object.traverse( function ( child ) {

                                if ( child.isMesh ) {
                                    child.material.map = texture;
                                    }
                                } );

                            // object.position.y = 20;
                            object.scale.set(2.54, 2.54, 2.54);
                            object.position.copy( intersect.point ).add( intersect.face.normal );
                            // objects.push( object );
                            obj3d.add(object)
                            // scene.add(object)
                            animate();

                            }, manager.onProgress, manager.onError );

                        }


                }

            }

            //

            function animate() {
                // requestAnimationFrame(animate)
                // controls.update();
                composer.render();

            }

            function render() {

                // for looking at the center
                // camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .05;
                // camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .05;

                // camera.lookAt( scene.position );
                // pick(pickPosition, scene, camera);
                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

            function addSelectedObject( object ) {
                selectedObjects = [];
                selectedObjects.push( object );
            }

            function pick(normalizedPosition, scene, camera) {
              // restore the color if there is a picked object
              if (pickedObject) {
                // pickedObject.material.emissive.setHex(pickedObjectSavedColor);
                pickedObject = undefined;
              }

              // cast a ray through the frustum
              raycaster.setFromCamera(normalizedPosition, camera);
              // get the list of objects the ray intersected
              const intersectedObjects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);
              if (intersectedObjects.length) {
                // pick the first object. It's the closest one
                pickedObject = intersectedObjects[0].object;
                addSelectedObject( pickedObject );
                outlinePass.selectedObjects = selectedObjects;;

                // save its color
                // pickedObjectSavedColor = pickedObject.material.emissive.getHex();
                // set its emissive color to flashing red/yellow
                // pickedObject.material.emissive.setHex((time * 8) % 2 > 1 ? 0xFFFF00 : 0xFF0000);
              }
            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Expected Result:
Whenever my mouse is on an object, that object should get highlighted else stay as unhighlighted

Actual Result:
Once the object is loaded into the scene, the outline shows up for that model but when I move to other objects in the scene, nothing happens

Comment: `mouse = new THREE.Vector2();` you don't change it so you get same array of objects. see https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster

Comment: Please demonstrate your issue with a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/).